# SwashBuckle.AspNetCore.Cli "No service for type ISwaggerProvider has been registered" Error

Tags: c#, swagger, .net-5, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have a WebApi Project in .Net 5 and have already been using Swagger with default setup (services.AddSwaggerGen() in ConfigureServices method & app.UseSwagger() and app.UseSwaggerUI() in Configure method in Startup.cs) without any issues.

Now I decided to create Swagger Files via Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.
I created manifest file:
`.net new tool-manifest`

and then installed Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli:`dotnet tool install --version 6.2.3 Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli`

All is fine until here. Also checked to see if it is working via `dotnet swagger tofile --help`, and it is.

Now when I want to create json file via `dotnet swagger tofile --output api.json bin\Debug\net5.0\MyApiApi.dll v1`, I get

> System.InvalidOperationException: **No service for type 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.ISwaggerProvider' has been registered.**
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.Program.<>c.b__0_4(IDictionary`2 namedArgs) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\Program.cs:line 82 at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.CommandRunner.Run(IEnumerable`1 args) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\CommandRunner.cs:line 68
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.CommandRunner.Run(IEnumerable`1 args) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\CommandRunner.cs:line 59
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\Program.cs:line 121

exception. I have not been able to detect the cause.
I am already using

- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (6.2.3)
- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger  (6.2.3)
- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations (6.2.3),
- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft (6.2.3)

Has anyone any idea what could be causing that problem? Note that it is different than "unable to resolve service" error, which could be resolved by adding services.AddSwaggerGen() in Startup.cs. I already use that since Swagger is already in use in this project.

Comment: There is an issue opened on github for this error: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/763

Answer (score 1):

Update your packages, the issue has been fixed. This used to be an issue on the GitHub page under [Issue #763](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/763) and has since been resolved.